# Validate date in DD-MM-YYYY” Format in php

Tags: php

Can this format  `10-7-2010` validated with php?
With this script:

```
$array = explode('-', $str);
$day = $array[0];
$month = $array[1];
$year = $array[2];
$Valid = checkdate($month, $day, $year);
```

I have this error:

```
checkdate() expects parameter 2 to be long
```

How can I validate such format?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Works here! http://codepad.viper-7.com/0idtfL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing to:
`$Valid = checkdate((int)$month, (int)$day, (int)$year);`

edit: I tried your code and it works fine, could it be you have an poorly formatted date somewhere you're trying to pass in?

edit2: 10-7-2007 is a valid date, but it sounds like you think it should not be?  It is a date in the past, so if you are trying to determine if a date is in the future, you could do something like this:

`$isValid = ( strtotime("$year-$month-$day") > time() );`

Comment: There's no reason he should have to. This will only hide bugs.

Comment: Thanks, Now there is not any error. But yet the 10-7-2007 is valid :(

Comment: May there is a space or hidden char at this end of the string

Comment: @M42 If there were, it would be discarded by the conversion to number when the string was passed to checkdate.

Answer (score 0):

and thank you for your help guys. I finally got a completed code (with other conditions).

I'm posting it here, hoping that it might help someone.

```
<?php
function valid_date($date) // if the date is valid, then the function returns true. else returns false.
{
    $array = explode('/', $date, 3);
    if (strlen($date) == 10 && substr_count($date, '/') == 2 && checkdate($array[1], $array[0], $array[2]) && substr_count($date, ' ') == 0) {
        return true;
    } Else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks